# Modify freevars in Python does not work?

Tags: python, closures

I'm trying to attach an integer variable to any exist function to record the number of times it has been called. To do this, I wrote down the following decorator.

```
def count(fun):
  n = 0
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    n += 1
    print "%s called %d times" % (fun.func_name, n)
    fun(*args, **kwargs)
  return wrapper
```

But it does not work, because n in the inner function wrapper is not treated as the same n in the outer scope count. I'm wondering why is this the case?

I know one way I can circumvent this limitation is using mutable container like list to put the number n in .

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
def count(fun):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.n += 1
        print("%s called %d times" % (fun.__name__, wrapper.n))
        fun(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.n = 0
    return wrapper

@count
def test():
    print('hello')

def main():
    for i in range(5):
        test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 you would use the `nonlocal` keyword (as opposed to `global`):

```
def count(fun):
    n = 0

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal n

        n += 1
        print("{} called {} times".format(fun.__name__, n))
        fun(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

But I'm guessing from your code you're looking for a Python 2 solution.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python2, our team will switch to Python3 next year.